# How can be sent an auto-generated email to a user when some other user invites him on my website "by isuing the java code"

Tags: java, email, email-templates

I have a problem;
I want to write a java code for sending an automatic email to a registered user on my website when some other user invites him. Then the invitee will accept or reject the invitation inside the email.
Please guide me...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let him click a link in that email.

Email code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
public void sendEmail(String aFromEmailAddr, String aToEmailAddr,
    String aSubject, String aBody){
    //Here, no Authenticator argument is used (it is null).
    //Authenticators are used to prompt the user for user
    //name and password.
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance( fMailServerConfig, null );
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage( session );
    try {
      //the "from" address may be set in code, or set in the
      //config file under "mail.from" ; here, the latter style is used
      //message.setFrom( new InternetAddress(aFromEmailAddr) );
      message.addRecipient(
        Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(aToEmailAddr)
      );
      message.setSubject( aSubject );
      message.setText( aBody );
      Transport.send( message );
    }
    catch (MessagingException ex){
      System.err.println("Cannot send email. " + ex);
    }
  }
```

And you can put a link in that email. I believe basic HTML is supported in mail clients, so you can do something like:

```
Hi PersonWithANameEnteredByTheGuyWhoInvitedYou,

NameOfTheGuyWhoInvitedYou invited you, click here to accept his invitation:

<a href="http://mydomain.com/accept?param=ridiculousLongTokenToVerifyTheRequestAndIdentifyThePersonThatClickedIt">ACCEPT!</a>
```